# Dart2Js w/ Polymer Runtime-Error

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

My Dart-App works fine in Dartium, but when I compile to js there is this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'registerElement'
```

My pubspec looks like this:

```
name: Capira_v8
description: Capira v8
dependencies:
  bootjack: any
  ctrl_alt_foo: any
  event_bus: any
  js: any
  json_object: any
  polymer: any
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/capira_v8.html
```

I am using: 
Dart Editor version 1.2.0.release (STABLE) 
Dart SDK version 1.2.0 
OS X 10.8.5

I saw this thread, but it did not help: 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804452/polymer-dart2js-not-working)

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(symbols: const['registerElement'])
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

to your Dart file.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. 
Can you please specify which file you mean?
Do you mean the file in which the main method is or the files where I use polymer?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Some Dart file in your project where an import statement is allowed. It is to prevent tree-shaking 'registerElement'.The question you linked defines a specific polymer version. What Polymer-version do you use? (you see it when you expand the packages directory in DartEditor behind the name) or when you open the pubspec.lock file.

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not work.

polymer: 0.9.5,
polymer_expressions: 0.9.1

Comment: Hard to tell what could be the cause.

Comment: I solved it. 

There was a call of document.registerElement but in current Dartium there is only document.register supported.

By enabling enable-experimental-web-platform-features in Chrome it also works.

Comment: It's basically this issue: [link](https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements/issues/87)

Comment: fyi -- couple of notes regarding `@MirrorsUsed`. I don't think you would need it for registerElement. It's only for things used from {{ bindings }} or reflection operations like PathObserver("foo.bar")... if the name doesn't appear in a string or HTML file you probably don't  need MirrorsUsed. Also you can put `@reflectable` on the class or member instead of MirrorsUsed, which is easier IMHO.

Comment: Also: you should not need to turn on experimental features in Dartium. My guess is that you forgot to include the shadow_dom or custom_elements polyfill packages: pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element or pub.dartlang.org/packages/shadow_dom (note that these are in the process of being consolidated into pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components for polymer 0.10.0-pre.0)